# Multiple infoWindow in Google Map API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create multiple infowindow for multiple marker, But it seem like just refer to last infowindow

This is my code (in for loop, _lat and _long is unique value):

```
                        marker.addListener('click', function(){
                            //markerInfoWindow.close();
                            markerInfoWindow.setContent('<a href="#" onclick="onUnsavePlace(' + _lat + ',' + _long + ');">Unsave place</a>', true);
                            markerInfoWindow.open(map, this); 
                        }); 

                        marker.setMap(map);
```

I tested with marker, marker show correctly but all of them link to the last infoWindow.

How can I make new infoWindow for each Marker?

Update:

This is fully my function after update:

```
        function getListPosition(listMarkers, map){
            db.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Position', [], function(tx, rs) {
                    var numberOfItems = rs.rows.length; 

                    var markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var marker;

                    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {

                        var _lat = rs.rows.item(i).Lat;
                        var _long = rs.rows.item(i).Long;

                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: {lat: _lat , lng: _long}
                        });

                        listMarkers.push(marker);

                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
                            return function() {
                                markerInfoWindow.setContent('<a href="#" onclick="onUnsavePlace(' + _lat + ',' + _long + ');">Unsave place</a>', true);
                                markerInfoWindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker));

                        // marker.addListener('click', function(){
                        //     //markerInfoWindow.close();
                        //     markerInfoWindow.setContent('<a href="#" onclick="onUnsavePlace(' + _lat + ',' + _long + ');">Unsave place</a>', true);
                        //     markerInfoWindow.open(map, this); 
                        // }); 

                        marker.setMap(map); 

                        // Set map center to the last marker
                        if (i == numberOfItems - 1){
                            map.setCenter({lat: _lat, lng: _long});
                        } 

                    }

                });
            }, function(err){
                console.log('Error when get list position. Error code: ' + err.code);
            });
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: It doesn't work with my code

Comment: You need function closure on `_lat` and `_lng` as well as marker (or get them from the marker).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue if that doesn't help.

Comment: Can you explain me abit about this syntax:

    `(function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need function closure on the loop variables that are needed when the click listener function runs.  In your case `_lat` and `_lng`.  It would probably be simplest to just get those from the marker (`this`) though:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
  markerInfoWindow.setContent('<a href="#" onclick="onUnsavePlace(' + this.getPosition().lat() + ',' + this.getPosition().lng() + ');">Unsave place</a>', true);
  markerInfoWindow.open(map, this);
});
```

(not tested)

Comment: Oh, It works. But why it doesn't work with this:

`marker.addListener('click', function(){
                                //markerInfoWindow.close();
                                markerInfoWindow.setContent('<a href="#" onclick="onUnsavePlace(' + _lat + ',' + _long + ');">Unsave place</a>', true);
                                markerInfoWindow.open(map, this); 
                            });`

Comment: Because as I said in my answer and my comment, you don't have function closure on `_lat` and `_long`.

Comment: My mistake! Thank you!